Getting the domain of a real function with iterated logarithms
I would like to find the domain of the function
$$f(x)\:=\: \log_4\,\log_5\,\log_3\big(\,18x - x^2 - 77\,\big)$$
as a subset of $\mathbb R\,$.
I looked at the solution of the above problem, and it proceeded just as I hand-solved the problem:
It formed two inequalities
$$\log_5\,\log_3(\,18x - x^2- 77\,) \,>\, 0\ \text{ and }\  18x - x^2 - 77 \,>\, 0\,.$$
Simplifying both of these leads to the following two inequalities
$$8 < x < 10\ \text{ and }\ 7 < x < 11\,.$$
I could solve up to this point, however after this, things were not understood by me, in the solution to the above problem the author says that the domain of the function must be $(8,10)$,
i.e., $\,x \in (8, 10)$
Why is this the case, and why is the interval $\,(7, 11)\,$ ignored?
Any help would be appreciated.

Try reading "$8 < x < 10 \text{ and } 7 < x < 11$" as "$x \in (8,10) \cap (7,11)$"

@Henry Thanks for the answer, i understood it now!

Could you post an answer so i could accept it @Henry

Requested from comment
Try reading "$8 < x < 10 \text{ and } 7 < x < 11$"
as "$x \in (8,10) \cap (7,11)$".
$(8,10) \cap (7,11) = (8,10)$ so this becomes  $8 < x < 10$.

With nested logarithms, you need to work from the inside-out as this is how the functions have been composed. So, any value of $x$ for which $18x-x^{2}-77>0$ is not true is immediately excluded.
There is an assumption here that we are staying completely in the domain of the Reals, but I think that is a fair assumption.
